# How to compile Laravel 5.4 application using Sass and Compass

Tags: laravel, sass, compass

I'm trying to use a bootstrap theme/template built with the latest Bootstrap 3 and Sass (with Compass).

Searching a little bit about compass and reading the above post, I learned that I should compile all my sass files with Compass, which I did it. However, when opening my app in the browser I'm getting the following error:

Uncaught Error: Module build failed: ModuleBuildError: Module build failed:

```
@import "compass/typography";
```

The above import is inside a partial _base.scss file, which contains:

```
@import "compass/typography";
@import "compass/css3";
```

I'm using Laravel 5.4 and if I then try to compile my app using "npm run watch-poll" I basically get the same error:

Module build failed:

```
@import "compass/typography";
```

So, I would appreciate any help on how to deal with the above. Thanks a lot.

Comment: What is the folder structure for your scss files? Do you have all your sccs in a folder named compass?

Comment: Hi @Ruben, actually I cannot see a folder named compass. Since I'm working with Laravel, all my scss files are located in  /var/www/html/kingadmin/resources/assets/sass

Comment: Inside this folder I have another folder named partials, which has a file named _base.scss, which contains the compass folder explained above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem probably is that when you use the @import, you need to respect the folder structure.

So if your folder structure looks like this:

```
 - style.scss
 - partials
    - _base.scss
    - _typography.scss
```

Your import should look like this (assuming you are importing on style.scss):

```
@import "partials/typography";
```

Comment: Yes, I know that. However, I can't find the "compass" folder on the folder structure. It compiles successfully using "compass compile", but when I launch the application then I can see the above mentioned error.

Anyways, I thank you very much for your assistance. I will try to find another admin package. So I'm closing this discussion.